# select an option with specific text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox named '.dmmjobcontrol_category' in my html-document.
What I want to do is to select an option with a specific text.

I have found no way to do that, only to select a value.

Can anyone help me, please?

Regards, 
Chricken

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to achieve this (Assuming jquery is avaiblable in your code)

```
$('.dmmjobcontrol_category option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "Your needed value"
});
```

Or :contains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$(".dmmjobcontrol_category option:contains('Your needed value')")
```

Comment: ...what if one of the options is "Your needed value sucks"?

Comment: You're totally right, it will fail as it's not a strict match.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this last bit on the end to make sure it is actually the selected option.

```
$('.dmmjobcontrol_category option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Your needed value"
}).prop("selected", "true");
```